# Cyclic group of order 2 and its subrepresentations over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: representation-theory

I have $G=C_2 = \{e,g\}$ the cyclic group of order 2, and the map $\phi: G \to GL_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ given by

$$
e \to
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0 \\
    0       & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}, \,\,\,g \to
\begin{bmatrix}
    3       & -4 \\
    2       & -3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This is a 2d representation of $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$. From my understanding, there are at least two subrepresentations derived from the shared eigenvectors of these two matrices, which are $u = (1,1)$ and $w=(2,1)$. The spans of these eigenvectors give $U$ and $W$, respectively, and these are the two subrepresentations.

Then, I am asked to show in an exercise that the *inner* direct sum $U \oplus W= \mathbb{C}^2$.

But what is going on here? I understand that if I use the external direct sum, since these spans $\text{span}(u)$ and $\text{span}(w)$ are two planes (since $\phi$ is over $\mathbb{C}$), and the direct sum of any two non-parallel planes is $\mathbb{C}^2$, then $U \oplus W= \mathbb{C}^2$, but this is an inner direct sum? Can this direct sum of two subrepresentations work with the inner direct sum?

Perhaps the problem is that it is in fact just the external direct sum of the spans that we need to give $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Comment: Usually if you are given a space, and want to take the direct sum of two or more subspaces you call this the inner (or internal) direct sum, since the sums are occurring inside your main space. OTOH you can take any two spaces $A$ and $B$ and consider their direct sum $A \oplus B$, but since you didn't obtain these spaces as subspaces you refer to this as an external direct sum.

Comment: To show that the internal direct sum $U \oplus V \cong \mathbb{C}^2$ you need to construct an isomorphism. To start with, what should the matrix for $g$ be in terms of the basis $u$ and $w$, call it D (Hint: it will be diagonal). Now your isomorphism should be a $2 \times 2$ matrix, $T$ such that $T^{-1} \phi(g) T = D$, can you think of any candidates?

Comment: How do you form a matrix out of the basis $u$ and $v$?

Comment: In fact, $U \oplus V$ is a sub-representation of $\mathbb{C}^2$ with equal dimensions (as $\mathbb{C}$ vector spaces), so you can instantly conclude they are equal, however if this is from a problem set I suspect they may want you to be thinking about the isomorphism.

Comment: This is the method of diagonalising a matrix, since $u$ and $w$ is an eigenbasis - see [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixDiagonalization.html#:~:text=Matrix%20diagonalization%20is%20the%20process,properties%20of%20the%20underlying%20matrix.)

Comment: What I don't understand is how you take these span(u) and span(v), and then form a matrix for g. You don't just add them together in a weighted way? So basically, what is D?

Comment: Ok so its all about the diagonalisable idea.

Comment: Yea, alternatively compute $\phi(g)u = \lambda_1 u$ to find $\lambda_1 = -1$, and similarly find $\lambda_2$ for $v$, then your matrix $D$ is just $D = \text{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$

Comment: Have a think about this and if it's still confusing tag me tomorrow and I will write up a longer explanation explaining what's happening, but I am a little too tired right now.

Comment: Ok I can see, the u gets hit by the matrix, and we form the diagonal matrix for the isomorphism from the corresponding eigenvalues.